# Updating two columns in a table containing millions of rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am updating 2 columns in a table that contains millions (85 million) of rows. Now to update these I am using a update command like,

```
UPDATE Table1

  SET Table1.column1 = Table2.column1 ,
      Table1.column2 = Table2.column2 

FROM 
      Tables and with a Join-conditions;
```

Now my problem is, it is taking 23 hours for that. Even after using the batch size there is not much change in the time taken.

But I need to update it in less than 5 hours. Is that possible. What approach should I take to achieve it ?

Comment: You need to update the **entire** table?? The only thing I can think of right now is making sure the columns used in the JOINs between the tables are indexed

Comment: You should have a look at the query-plan. Perhaps there are some index that might help you.

Comment: @Amarnath I hope you're looking into partitioning the table some time soon.

Comment: @marc_s        Yes, I need to update the entire table's column-1 and column-2. The columns that are used in JOINS are indexed.

Comment: @dbaseman       Is that really necessary ? I don't know but I am really curious to know why to do that ? Since I heard that SQL-SERVER can hold large data which is more than 85-Million.

Comment: @Amarnath if not strictly necessary, it might save you some pain.  When maintenance tasks are measured in days, that does not seem workable.

Comment: @dbaseman ha ha true. Soon then I have to partition it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used SSIS for doing this task.

First I have taken the source table in which I have to update the 2-columns. Then I have taken Look-Up task in which I have to mapped source columns to the destination table columns from which I have to get the data to update source table columns. Finally added OLEDB destination from where I'll fill the table basing on the joining conditions from the look-up.

This process was really fast than executing an update script.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Update statements have to keep all the rows in the log file so it can roll-back on failure. As explained by [this guy](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3141), the best way to handle millions of rows is to forget about atomicity and batch your updates into 50,000 rows (or whatever):

```
--Declare variable for row count
Declare @rc int
Set @rc=50000

While @rc=50000
 Begin

  Begin Transaction

  --Use Top (50000) to limit number of updates
  --performed in each batch to 50K rows.
  --Use tablockx and holdlock to obtain and hold 
  --an immediate exclusive table lock. This unusually
  --speeds the update because only one lock is needed.
  Update Top (50000) MyTable With (tablockx, holdlock)
    Set UpdFlag = 0
  From MyTable mt
  Join ControlTable ct
    On mt.KeyCol=ct.PK
  --Add criteria to avoid updating rows that
  --were updated in previous pass
  Where m.UpdFlag <> 0

  --Get number of rows updated
  --Process will continue until less than 50000
  Select @rc=@@rowcount

  --Commit the transaction
  Commit
 End
```

This still has some problems in that you need to know which rows you've already handled, perhaps someone smarter than this guy (and me!) can figure something nicer with more MSSQL magic; but this should be a start.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) you should use `update top(50000)` instead. "Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in the next release of SQL Server."

Comment: @Simon Buchan  Thanks. I'll try this and will soon post the update.

Comment: @Simon Buchan   I have used "Look-up" for doing this task and I got successful results.

Comment: @Mikael: OK, I'll edit that in (it sure seems way less magic!)

Comment: @Amarnath: Sorry, I'm not sure what "Look-up" is, and failed Googling it. If it's some MSSQL feature that makes for a nicer loop, I'd love to improve my answer!

Comment: @SimonBuchan   I have used SSIS for doing this task. First I have taken the source table in which I have to update the 2-columns. Then I have taken Look-Up task in which I have to mapped source columns to the destination table columns from which I have to get the data to fill the source table columns. Finally added OLEDB destination from where I'll fill the table basing on the joining conditions from the look-up. This process was really fast than what I have thought.

Comment: @Amarnath: Ahh, sounds like deep magic is probably happening. Probably worth adding as a different answer, since it's not a tweak to this - I'll leave that to someone who understands SSIS (I'm just a simple developer and only understand spitting SQL at things!)